# What is the following (matrix) operator called?

Tags: matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & \cdots & A_{1m} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} & \cdots & A_{2m} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\ A_{m1} & A_{m2} & \cdots & A_{mm}  \end{bmatrix}$ be a block matrix where each $A_{ij}$, $1\leq i,j\leq m$, is an

$n\times n$ matrix. Define operator $VB$ by

$VB(\mathbf{A})=\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} \\ A_{21} \\ \vdots \\ A_{m1} \\ A_{12} \\ \vdots \\ A_{mm} \end{bmatrix}$

What is called operator $VB$? Is there any reference about its properties?

Comment: This is not exactly an operator: this is an isomorphism between two distinct vector spaces. What kind of properties do you want to know?

Comment: We have vec operator of a scalar matrix. I want some proposition related with famous matrix operator (for example, usual and kronecker product with other matrices, etc)

Comment: My friend and collaborator A. I. Solomon used to call this operation "the stringing" (pronounce like "a stringed instrument"), he said, you stringe them. I met also this operation in genetic algorithms (I'll try to find a reference)

Comment: I would say $blkvec$ following the $diag$ case

Answer (score 1):

the inverse of $VB$ maps a tensor onto a matrix; this operation is called  [matricization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matricization) (or unfolding or flattening), see [this paper](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~bersa48/files/elden09.pdf) by Lars Eldén and Berkant Savas (2009).